# How do I make an Auto Clicker Macro in Lua script inside Logitech ghub? please

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

The code works completely, but I need it to work on button 1?. I changed the buttons for place 5 to 1, it doesn’t work.

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      repeat
 MoveMouseRelative(0,10)
         Sleep(15)
         PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(15)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) 
   end
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In the game, in the "Controls Settings", introduce alternative key for "Shoot" action.
   For example, let it be keyboard key <kbd>P</kbd>.
   So, now in the game you can shoot either using Left Mouse Button or using Keyboard key <kbd>P</kbd>.
   Of course, you will use LMB for manual shooting as usually, but your GHub script will use <kbd>P</kbd>.
2. The script

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 1 then
      repeat
         MoveMouseRelative(0,10)
         Sleep(15)
         PressAndReleaseKey("P")  -- instead of PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(15)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) 
   end
end
```

Comment: autoclick does not work, and caps lock

Comment: EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents  (true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("CapsLock")then
                        if IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,30)
         Sleep(10)
         PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(10)
PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
Sleep(10)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
                end
end

            end

Comment: this is how everything works only through button 4

Comment: если я ставлю букву "P" то код вообще не работает , помоги пожалуйста

Comment: EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents  (true);
function OnEvent(event,arg)
    if IsKeyLockOn("CapsLock")then
                        if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
                    repeat
                        MoveMouseRelative(0,30)
         Sleep(10)
      PressAndReleaseKey("P") 
         Sleep(10)
     PressAndReleaseKey("P")
Sleep(10)
                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
                end
end

            end

Comment: автоклик  неработает

Comment: пункт 1 выполнил?  проверить можно, нажав кнопку P в игре, это должно дать такой же эффект, как и выстрел левой кнопкой мыши.  после того, как сможешь кнопкой P стрелять, ставь скрипт

Comment: я так и сделал , после этого он выстреливает один и ведет мышь вниз это окей. Но мне надо чтобы он постоянно кликал по левай кнопкой мышы и вел вниз

Comment: проверь по каждому из пунктов: 1) можно стрелять ЛКМ, 2) можно стрелять кнопкой P, 3) при нажатой ЛКМ можно стрелять кнопкой P, 4) при нажатой кнопке P можно стрелять ЛКМ.  какие пункты работают, какие нет?